Is POD24 diagnosed from the beginning of treatment or the end of treatment to relapse date?
Is POD24 diagnosed from the beginning of treatment or the end of treatment to relapse date?
Whether or not the beginning of the POD24 timeframe is when chemo begins or ends varies by at least four months thus can determine whether a patient has a poor prognosis or not.

Observational studies and stand-alone trials indicate that patients
with follicular lymphoma (FL) who experience disease progression
within 24 months of front-line chemoimmunotherapy (POD24), have poor
outcomes...
Early FL relapse, defined as recurrence or progression of disease
within 24 months of front-line treatment (POD24), has been noted to
occur in 20% of patients who receive first-line chemoimmunotherapy and
is associated with particularly poor outcomes.

Validation of POD24 as a robust early clinical end point of poor survival in FL from 5225 patients on 13 clinical trials
https://ashpublications.org/blood/article/139/11/1684/477185/Validation-of-POD24-as-a-robust-early-clinical-end
First-line chemoimmunotherapy is the first set of treatments for a disease that includes chemotherapy and immunotherapy:

The answer is from the beginning of treatment (see below)
Survival by First-line Treatment Type and Timing of Progression Among Follicular Lymphoma Patients: A National Population-based Study in Sweden

Definition of progression of disease POD was defined as either progressive disease as best response to first-line therapy, initial
response but later relapse/progression as indication for second-line
therapy, or transformation. Patients not (yet) fulfilling any of these
criteria were considered progression-free (PF). Date of POD was
subsequently defined as date of first-line evaluation, second-line
treatment initiation date, or date of first transformation (after
first-line treatment). POD24 was defined as fulfilling any of the
above criteria within 24 months after start of first-line
treatment. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9953041

Prognosis of Progressive Follicular Lymphoma within 24 Months of First-Line Therapy Is Not Influenced By the Initial Regimen Intensity

Progression of follicular lymphoma (FL) within 24 months of
initiating first-line therapy (POD24) is a strong driver of poor
outcomes and is associated with a high risk of transformation.
https://ashpublications.org/blood/article/142/Supplement%201/6150/505600/Prognosis-of-Progressive-Follicular-Lymphoma

Impact of early relapse within 24 months after first-line systemic therapy (POD24) on outcomes in patients with marginal zone lymphoma: A US multisite study

POD24 was defined as relapse or progression of MZL within 24 months
of initiation of systemic therapy.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10165748/

